# Middleware - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una duda sobre los middleware

**Lo que deseo hacer:**

Que un usuario logueado no pueda ir a ninguna ruta si no da clic a una cuadro que aparece en pantalla.
no se si esto se pueda hacer con los middleware ya que con ello controlo la restricción de rutas según el rol que tenga el usuario.

Habría alguna forma de realizar esto?
alguna idea ?

Saludos.

Comment: Los middleware también pueden contener funciones, puedes poner a tus rutas algún tipo de clave, un middleware general que recoga la ruta de donde viene, y descomponga la ruta, sino encuentra esa " clave ", es que no han pulsado.

Comment: podrías darme un ejemplo, soy nuevo en laravel

Comment: Pues no puedo, porque PHP lo tengo en casa, échale un ojo a https://ajgallego.gitbooks.io/laravel-5/content/capitulo_2_filtros.html  .Del mismo modo que recoges el rol mediante la sesión, puedes pasarle la ruta de donde vienes al handler y comprobar.